# How to recursively create a hash file (sha512sum) inside each folder of a tree?

Tags: bash-scripting, hashing, recursion

For a given tree, say /var/ftpd, how do I create a hash file in each folder of that tree with the contents of that folder within a given tree?  sha1sum and sha512sum does not have recursion options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FWIW the solution is:

```
user@host bin]$ cat mkshaindir 
#!/bin/dash
cd $1
sha512sum * >.sha512sum

[user@host bin]$ find /var/ftpd -type d -print0 | xargs -0 -i  mkshaindir  {}
```

Note that mkshaindir, for my purposes, is a separate component because there may be a need for me to make a hash of files in a new folder, or of one that was recently changed.

The rest is left as an exercise for the reader.

Note: sha512sum will complain to STDERR about non file input (e.g. directories, block files, etc).

Comment: +1, though some details might be nice. (e.g. the -print0 xargs-0 to work around 'interesting' filenames. the -type d to select only directries in find, ...)

Comment: Hennes, with apologies to Dickens, are there no googles?  Are there no man pages?

Comment: Yup . Also anoying betknowers who know it all. 
Still, simplest to the people reading this if we pad it just a tad more.

Comment: People come to this site for a solution or for inspiration. Those that seek a solution will cut-n-paste and not think to ask how or why. Those that seek inspiration, like myself, will read the man pages and google for themselves. The former won't care about a discussion and the latter might but would only read it if they could not "get it" by doing their own research.

Answer (score 0):

The script should avoid to include the hashfile itself into the calculation, as saving the hashfile invalidates the hash.
Moreover, I suggest to use `find -exec` to save resources:

```
find /var/ftpd -type d -print0 ! -name .sha512sum -exec mkshaindir {} \;
```

Comment: Your statement is true if \* found hidden files (aka dot files [e.g. .profile]). Ergo the reason to use a dot file for storing the hash values. A hash file is not invalidated because ONE line is failing. sha512sum -c hashfile will report a single file has failure not that the whole file is invalid. A person with some familiarity on the process would understand that it is the chicken/egg problem and ignore the one failing line in a file that was not applicable.

Comment: I was thinking of a more general case where you would check a subtree for changed files. As such, I would not exclude dot-files by principle, and secondly I'd check the subtree by a script and it's exit value (any one file changed - not a single file changed in subtree). So either I filter for `.sha512sum` when creating the checksum, or when checking the checksum files. But for your use case I agree generality doesn't count.